# Is there a way to know when the WebHostBuilder.Run() or WebHostBuilder.RunAsync() starts successfully?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code, not exactly, but the basic idea is the same:

```
IWebHost hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseKestrel(ConfigureKestrelOptions)
    .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
    .Build();

try
{
    await hostBuilder.RunAsync(cancellationToken);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Do some stuff

    throw;
}
```

Where `Startup` is a custom class, `ConfigureKestrelOptions` and `ConfigureServices` are private methods and `cancellationToken` is predefined by the outside code and used when stopping the server is desired.

When the startup of the server fails, the most common case being when the port is already open, the `RunAsync` throws and we can intercept the exception as shown here, display errors, retry, etc.

But when the `RunAsync` method succeeds, the call blocks until the server is closed, normally by the intermediary of the `CancellationToken`. It does of course the same if the call is done synchronously with `Run`.

I want to be able to do something when `RunAsync`is a success, and not when it fails. Is there a way to pass to the `WebHostBuilder` a continuation that is executed when the port is successfully opened and the `WebHostBuilder` is running successfully ? If yes, how ?

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/finding-the-urls-of-an-aspnetcore-app-from-a-hosted-service-in-dotnet-6/

Comment: ^^ I used that to download the swagger.json file for my API as soon as the web server was ready to respond.

Comment: @madreflection This link helped me tremendously to solve this problem. Would you care to make a formal answer from what it explains ? Else I'll formulate and accept it myself.

Comment: There was nothing specific about what you needed to do on successful startup, so I would be unable to write an answer for that. The article is perfect, and it helped you. Really, only you can post an answer since you know the specifics of your situation; all that leaves for me to do is plagiarize the article, which I won't do.